# Retrying Durable Function activity/orchastrator later

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless, azure-durable-functions

Consider the following scenario:

My orchestrator `O` starts, and calls sub-orchestrator `S`. `S` succeeds in processing activities `A1` and `A2` but fails in `A3`. I have automatic retries on `A3`, but no luck (the webservice i'm calling is giving a 404). No problem, I catch the exception and perform cleanup for `A1` and `A2`.

Eventually I need to retry the process.
What is the proper way to do this?

My current approach was going to be, writing a message to a custom poison queue with a visibility delay, and then having another AZ func that pulls from this queue, and restarts the sub-orchestrator.

It would also be ideal if i could restart the same sub-orchestrator with the same invocation ID. Theoretically this could save me from having to redo `A1` and `A2` as well as their cleanup!

Is this the correct line of thinking, or am I misusing durable functions?

Comment: please describe the activities A1, A2, A3 and then we can tell you if your architecture is appropirate

Answer (score 1):

There is an API - [Rewind Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management#rewind-instances-preview) **(Preview)** - that I believe you can use for this. You need the orchestration instance ID to use this.

You should be able to [query for failed instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management#query-instances-with-filters), filter based on [custom status](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/api/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DurableOrchestrationStatus.html#Microsoft_Azure_WebJobs_DurableOrchestrationStatus_CustomStatus) and then call rewind on them.

Comment: I'll look into this! Thanks